# The widgets in a new activity not showing up

Tags: user-interface, android-intent

I am working on an application that has a button which will lead to a new activity.  I managed to make that work but when I am trying to add a button in the new activity with xml it is not showing up.  I tried to make it work with programming but I was only able to make a button big as the whole screen.  When I tried to change the size of the button with programming it could not work.  Can someone please tell me how can I make that widgets show on the new activity preferably using XML.

This is the code of my first activity:

```
package com.example.user.myapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;





public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    public void sendButton(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Ut.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And this is the code of my second activity:

```
package com.example.user.myapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.content.Intent;
public class Ut extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_ut);




    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and this is the code that I added after Intent intent = getIntent() when I tried to make it work with programming

```
Button button2 = new Button(this);


        button2.setWidth(10);
        button2.setHeight(10);
        setContentView(button2);
```

With this code a button big as the whole screen showed up although I set the size of it.

Can somebody tell me how I can make this work?